# MySQL covering indexes and LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

I'm reading "High Performance MySQL", O'Reilly, 2nd edition.
Page 122:

> MySQL can't perform the LIKE operation in the index. etc

In the same page, the subsequent example is (there's an index on actor,title,prod_id):

`EXPLAIN SELECT *
 FROM products
     JOIN (
         SELECT prod_id
         FROM products
         WHERE actor='SEAN CARREY' AND title LIKE '%APOLLO%'
     )
 AS t1 ON (t1.prod_id=products.prod_id)\G`

Then it states:

> Now MySQL uses the covering index in the first stage of the query, when it finds matching rows in the subquery in the FROM clause.

I don't understand why, the LIKE statement is still there...

Comment: ...first stage of the query... `actor=SEAN CARREY` criteria is covered by the index.

Comment: @raina77ow thank you, let me understand... so it uses the index, but then for records with `actor='SEAN CARREY'` it does a normal table access to perform the LIKE operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am *assuming* the table is `InnoDB`.

```
SELECT prod_id
     FROM products
     WHERE actor='SEAN CARREY' AND title LIKE '%APOLLO%'
```

is handled in `INDEX(actor, title, prod_id)` because it is "covering"

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

is not "covered" because (I assume) there are a lot of other fields in `*`.

The "trick" they are demonstrating is:

1. Do all the searching in the index, on the assumption that is is much smaller than the table.  Note:  The index is a BTree; the table is a different BTree.
2. Get the `PRIMARY KEY` values from step 1.  That is, get a list of `prod_id`.
3. Efficiently look up the rest of the data (`*`) by using the `PRIMARY KEY` into the table `products`.

Suppose there were 40 rows with `actor='SEAN CARREY'`, and only 3 *of them* had `title LIKE '%APOLLO%'`.  Let's compare two approaches:

```
SELECT * FROM products
    WHERE actor='SEAN CARREY' AND title LIKE '%APOLLO%'
```

1. Look into `INDEX(actor, ...)` to find 40 `prod_id`.
2. Reach over into the data 40 times.
3. Filter out the ones without the desirable `title`.
4. Deliver 3 rows.

In an I/O bound (read: huge table), this would be the I/O count:

1. 1 block probably contains all 40 *index* entries; they would be together because the first part of the index was the same.
2. Close to 40 blocks would need to be looked at in the table.

Total:  About 41 units of work.

Now look at the query with the subquery.

1. Scan the index only.  Again 1 block.
2. Reach into the main table 4 times.

Total:  4 units of work.

4 << 41, so the more complex query actually runs faster.  (You are not likely to really see a full 10x improvement--because of a lot of details I left out.)

Comment: Thank you. What I still don't grasp, is why is the index covering. The LIKE statement isn't in a prefixed form, and the book states that in such case the index can't be used... So your "1. Scan the index only" should be invalid...

Comment: "Covering" -- Think of that `INDEX(actor, title, prod_id)` as being a "table" with those 3 columns and that index being its `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then ask "Can I do `SELECT ...` from that 'table' to get what I want?"  The answer is 'yes'.  However, it won't be very optimal because of the leading `%`.

Answer (score 0):

As index are work from left to right so left side should not be variable if you want to use index-

If your title field is indexed then check as per below-

```
title like '%APOLLO%' : Will not use index

title like '%APOLLO' : Will not use index

title like 'APOLLO%' : Will use index

title like 'APOLLO' : Will use index
```

In your case sub-query is not required as you can get same results by simple query and if actor field is indexed then query will use only this index.